# Private instance method on Object behaves different than in other classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is my code inheritance using the Object class:

```
class Object
  private
  def talk
    puts "hi there"
  end
end

class Child
  talk  # outputs 'hi there'
end
```

And here is my code inheritance with a new class:

```
class Parent
  private
  def talk
    puts "hi there"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  talk #`<class:Child>': undefined local variable or method `talk' for Child:Class (NameError)
end
```

Why would this behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both examples, you call `talk` within the context of `Child`, which is an instance of `Class` class.

In the first example, instance method `talk` is defined on `Object` class, which `Class` is a subclass of.

In the second example, instance method `talk` is defined on `Parent` class, which `Class` is not a subclass of.